# user editable Freeform emails

Tags: templates, solspace-freeform, low-variables

I'm building an event registration website at the moment and I'm looking for a way to allow the site owners to modify the content of emails sent by Freeform (v3 free version).

As I'm using Low Variables, I tried just adding the Low var to into the notification template and I also tried embedding a template.

I have considered using MX Notify Control but while that allows for customisation of the email templates, it's limiting in others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeform 4 ([free version](http://www.solspace.com/software/license/freeform/free/)) supports plugins in the “Email Message” notification field.

It should be possible to use one of Low Variables tags instead of the simple global variable syntax:

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="my_low_variables_var"}
```

Or you could write your own simple plugin that outputs whatever you want.

But I dont’t know if plugin usage in notifications works with Freeform 3. It’s worth a try I would say.

---

Another way could be to use hidden input fields that contain content for the notification mails. You can use Channel data, Low Variables, …:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{my_low_variables_var}">
```

This isn’t very secure in Freeform 3 (or earlier versions of Freeform 4) because it would be easy to manipulate the value of those fields prior submit.

But Jim Wyse from Solspace [postet on December 7](http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewreply/57953/):

> Freeform 4+ now stores the information that was in hidden fields prior
>   in a parameters table and calls them with the parameter ID, so those
>   are no longer exposed as hidden fields.

This is cool.

---

If there aren’t any reasons to not upgrade to Freeform 4 (free version), I would suggest the upgrade and one of the two solutions above.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I didn't realise that Freeform 4 had a free version.